# Bonus property of dense set decomposition?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a topological space X can be written as the union of two dense sets A and B, i.e. both intersect every open $\emptyset\neq U\subseteq X$. Supposing X has no finite open sets (but $\emptyset$), can A and B be always chosen such that they intersect each U on a set the size of U?

Comment: I think there is a name for this extra property, probably among the students of resolvability (which is what this property (a space is a disjoint union of dense sets) is called, as you might know). Maximally resolvable spaces (like metric spaces without isolated points) have this property I think.

Comment: That's bad news, I was hoping that max resolvable spaces don't have it in general. That's because I proved that spaces with $w(X) \leq\Delta (X)$ are max resolvable into dense sets with the extra property, providing they satisfy some very weak non-degeneracy condition. It is known that the inequality implies max resolvability and if the extra property can be really obtained at no extra cost, then my result is of no use :/

Comment: So in fact the question is: if a space satisfies $w(X)\leq\Delta (X)$, and hence is max resolvable, can the dense sets be chosen extra dense?

Answer (score 1):

A partial result:

Suppose $X = A \cup B$ where $A,B$ are infinite, dense and disjoint.
I claim that $A$ and $B$ can also be chosen to have the same cardinality.

Suppose $\kappa= |A| > |B|$, then partition $A$ into $\kappa$ many disjoint sets of size $\kappa$, say $A = \cup_{\alpha < \kappa} A_\alpha$.

Suppose that none of the sets $A \setminus A_\alpha$ is dense in $X$. Then for every $\alpha <\kappa$ there is some $b_\alpha \in B$ such that $b_\alpha \notin \overline{A \setminus A_\alpha}$ (or else $B \subseteq \overline{A \setminus A_\alpha}$, which would make $A \setminus A_\alpha$ dense...). The map from $\kappa$ to $B$ defined by $\alpha \rightarrow b_\alpha$ is not injective (as $|B| < \kappa$), so for some $\alpha, \beta < \kappa$ we have $b = b_\alpha = b_\beta$. But then $\overline{A} = \overline{A \setminus (A_\alpha \cap A_\beta)} = \overline{A\setminus A_\alpha} \cup \overline{A \setminus A_\beta}$ does not contain $b$, contradicting the denseness of $A$.

So some $A \setminus A_\alpha$ is dense. But then we can write $X$ as the disjoint union of $A \setminus A_\alpha$ (of size $\kappa$) and $B \cup A_\alpha$ of size $\kappa$.

So for the open set $X$ the answer is yes...

This idea might be extensible to other open sets as well.